# Is it "okay" to have a div with a great number of height?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I was having a great problem today with my css code, and after hours and hours of trying to solve a problem, I found out that the best solution to my problem is to set the `<div>` tag which was causing all of that noise to the height of `height: 100000000px` just to get rid of all of that headache.

so regardless of which problem I was trying to figure out, is it okay to have a div set to great number of height,

Note that this solution didn't result in showing x/y scrollbars , so nothing would actually be seen, it's just a parent div which instead of having its height set to `100%` is a div having its height set to `1000000px`.

Would this cause slawness in the web application?

Comment: *so regardless of which problem I was trying to figure out* --> I am pretty sure that if you ask a question about your problem you will get answers where you don't need hacks like setting a big height

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to have a div with a height of 1000000px, but it is **not recommended**. Having such a large value for the height of an element can cause **performance issues**, particularly on devices with limited resources, such as mobile devices or older computers. Additionally, it may cause issues with scrolling or layout on the page. It's better to use % or vh instead of px. Anyway even if the overflow is set to hidden, having a div with a height of 1000000px can still affect performance in several ways:

1. The browser will still need to allocate memory to render the element, even if it's not visible. This can cause the browser to slow down or become unresponsive.
2. The browser will need to perform layout calculations to determine the position and size of the element, and its child elements. This can be computationally expensive, particularly if the element has a large number of child elements.
3. The browser will need to repaint the element whenever it is scrolled into view. This can cause the browser to become unresponsive or to display visual artifacts.

But let's focus on the third point. If the element is only scrolled into view once and it's not frequently updated, then the performance impact may be minimal. However, if the element is frequently scrolled into view, or if the element is updated frequently, then the performance impact may be more significant.

Additionally, the performance impact will also depend on the specific device and browser in use. Some devices and browsers may be better equipped to handle large elements than others.

It's important to note that any performance issues caused by having a large element are likely to be cumulative and will depend on the total number of large elements and other resources on the page. It's always a good idea to ***minimize the use of large elements*** and other resources in order to ensure optimal performance.

I have no idea what caused you to use 1000000px for the height, but **I would never recommend it**.

Answer (score -1):

It does not make the webpage slow. You can give it as much height as you want.But instead of px i use rem because it is good for making the website more responsive.